# Where is my mistake in this power distribution system homework question?

Tags: power-engineering, homework

I have attempted to solve this problem, but the answers don't match. Where am I making a mistake?

[image: power distribution question and attempted answer]

Comment: What problem? What answer?

Comment: Mistake: not showing how you worked out your answer (and the little problem of not revealing the question). If you are as good at checking your questions as checking your answers then I'm not surprised.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no power distribution system question/problem and therefore there can be no answer.

Comment: Apologies. I am new to this site. I attached the image from my pc while typing the question. Anyways, here is the image containing the attempted solution. https://imgur.com/a/IDfG9Iz

Comment: @UmarWarraich - Welcome :-) I have inserted the image "inline" to make it easier for readers, and voted to re-open. In future, I recommend that (since you said you are using a PC), you click Ctrl+G in the edit box, to use the "guided" method of inserting an image. It is possible to type the syntax manually, but is is more work. Also, please read the [tour] and [help] to see how Stack Exchange sites are different from typical internet forums. Finally, after you ask a question, check back frequently, so that you can see (and quickly fix!) problems which are reported in comments. Again, welcome!

Comment: I only see one wire in your diagram.

Comment: @Spehro, it's a distribution diagram rather than a circuit diagram. I suspect though, that you may have let the cat out of the bag.